# TinyMCE on react, using noneditable_regexp prop. issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

i'm having an issue with my TinyMCE editor, where i'm setting this prop to my **init** function **noneditable_regexp** which gets every text that matches with the test and convert into a nonEditable component inside the editor (means it if someone backspace/delete, it will remove the whole block instead each character).

Here is how it is after the regexp recognizes {{params.project_title}} as a mceNonEditable:

[image: Show how it is]

It is working fine to convert it to a 'block' as you can see {{params.project_title}} that is converted to a `<span class="mceNonEditable">{{params.project_title}}</span>` because of the prop added to the init method from mce, but whenever I try to apply style by blicking on the bars, after selecting the block, it does nothing, it doesnt apply the style to it.

Only if I delete the variable, select the styles before inserting, and finally insert it. then the variable should contain the style changes.

Wasn't it supposed to work with pre defined span blocks with  **mceNonEditable** class?

Answer (score 0):

Update the tinymce to a higher version above (4.3.0) and both properties should be working.